# how to set hyper link for the field in tables that contain grouping in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression, report

I am building report in SSRS, and the tables contains department column and Tickets column, I did group parent by department so now I have tickets column have multi value in one column and I want to make hyper link for each ticket that can take me to specific URL with ticket id.
I try to use action and go to URL, but all tickets go to one URL because they are in one column so how can I make this happen.

[image]

Comment: Show the expression you have tried, grouping should be irrelevant assuming that the links will be on the number on the left in your image?